# How can I add same click event in new node made by using cloneNode, appendChild. (in forEach() syntax)

Tags: javascript, html, css, foreach, appendchild

My purpose is to make an infinite imageview function.

So I succeeded adding same movement, and new element using `cloneNode`, `appendChild`, but that button in the new element doesn't work with the same click event.

How can I add same click event to new elements?

```js
let listMarginTop = 70;
let listMarginLeft = 40;
let list = document.getElementById('firstLine');
let lists = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
let listsArr = [...lists];
let z = 10;
let transDelay = 1;
let xBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('xBtn');
let xBtnArr = [...xBtn];

for(let i = 0; i < listsArr.length; i++)
{
    listsArr[i].style.transition = 'all 0.5s linear ' + transDelay + 's';
    transDelay -= 0.1;
    listsArr[i].style.zIndex = z;
    z--;
    listsArr[i].style.marginTop = listMarginTop + 'vh';
    listsArr[i].style.marginLeft = listMarginLeft + 'vw';
    listMarginTop -= 6;
    listMarginLeft -= 6;
}
let lastChildMarginTop = 12;
let lastChildMarginLeft = -20;
xBtnArr.forEach((x) => {
    x.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let copyWindow  = x.parentElement.parentElement.cloneNode(true);
        x.parentElement.parentElement.style.opacity = '0';
        copyWindow.style.marginTop = parseInt(list.lastChild.style.marginTop) - 6 + 'vh';
        copyWindow.style.marginLeft = parseInt(list.lastChild.style.marginLeft) - 6 + 'vw';
        copyWindow.style.zIndex = z;
        z--;
        lastChildMarginTop -= 6;
        lastChildMarginLeft -= 6;
        list.appendChild(copyWindow);
        let listChildArr = [...list.childNodes];
        listChildArr.forEach(win => {
            win.style.marginTop = parseInt(win.style.marginTop) + 6 + 'vh';
            win.style.marginLeft = parseInt(win.style.marginLeft) + 6 + 'vw';
        })
        xBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('xBtn');
        xBtnArr = [...xBtn];
        console.log(xBtnArr);
    })
})
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}


.rightMain
{
    height: 100vh;
    flex: 7;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}

ul li
{
    margin-top: -10vh;
    margin-left: -10vw;
    position: absolute;
}

.showWindow
{
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

.showWindow button
{
    margin: 0.5vw 0.5vw 0;
    width: 1vw;
    height: 1vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='rightMain' className='rightMain'>
            <div id="container">
                <ul id='firstLine'>
                    <li>
                        <div className='showWindow'>
                            <button className='xBtn'></button>
                            <button></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div className='showWindow'>
                            <button className='xBtn'></button>
                            <button></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div className='showWindow'>
                            <button className='xBtn'></button>
                            <button></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div className='showWindow'>
                            <button className='xBtn'></button>
                            <button></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div className='showWindow'>
                            <button className='xBtn'></button>
                            <button></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div className='showWindow'>
                            <button className='xBtn'></button>
                            <button></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div className='showWindow'>
                            <button className='xBtn'></button>
                            <button></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div className='showWindow'>
                            <button className='xBtn'></button>
                            <button></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div className='showWindow'>
                            <button className='xBtn'></button>
                            <button></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div className='showWindow'>
                            <button className='xBtn'></button>
                            <button></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why className? It doesn't look like react, for example.

Comment: Oh! It is react!! It does not work but...I seperate the code for snippet...

Answer (score 0):

You have to address 2 problems here -

1. There is no `className` attribute on HTML elements. You have to change that to `class` on each and every element so that it accepts the correct class and you are able to select the DOM Nodes correctly using the `getElementsByClassName()` method.
2. Since you have a vision to make an infinite image view, and instead of adding so many separate event listeners to each and every button, you can use Event Delegation. You can find Event Delegation explained [here](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). This would help you increase your application performance.

Comment: Oh! It is react!! It does not work but...I seperate the code for snippet...
According to your second way. Add event on li tag? not a button tag?

Comment: If it's react you can share the code through JSFiddle. Also not adding the event on li add it to the `<ul>`